# RAID settings in BIOS automatically reset

Tags: windows-7, bios, raid

I've been running a RAID 1 for years now. Recently, I reinstalled Windows. I did not TOUCH the BIOS but SATA mode was reset to IDE mode somehow. Then I reinstalled Windows in (unknowingly) IDE mode, and to switch back to RAID mode will basically force me to reformat, once again. What could be the culprit? Some kind of BIOS battery perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, most likely the bios battery, but there could be drivers that load and change settings based on their thought of what you've set-up

If you've not played with the bios (to get a specific combination of things running) then you're likely able to remove the battery, short the BIOS (look for your board's "bios password recovery" options, which usually short the bios.

Then re-install the battery and try changing just the date .. shuting down, turning on again to see if bios stayed set, or reverted.  Depending on the board, the battery could be a simple watch button type battery, or could be an older rectangular shaped one.

The watch battery type are fairly cheap so you could just replace it with the correct one.

Comment: For lack of better explanation as to the cause, I am assuming this is the correct answer.

Comment: Thanks, I thought someone had tampered with my laptop while I was on holiday. Had the same experience as @Rice, whatever the case this seems to explain the bios resetting.